# Download data for forex rates from yahoo finance in C#

Tags: c#

I want to create application using C# that will download the data for the different currency pairs from yahoo finance. The values i required are bid, ask, LastValue, High, Low, Change, ChangeinPercentage etc. and i am using the service provided by yahoo as below,

http://finance.yahoo.com/d/quotes.csv?s=EURUSD=X&s=USDJPY=X&f=sl1d1t1bahg&e=.csv

but, it is not returning all the values.
Any idea how to get all the values.

Comment: What is going wrong? Do you get no data or any errors?

Answer (score 3):

Yes. NOT FROM THERE.

Yahoo does not care what you want - they offer a specific service. As you find out it does not provide what you want. So - go somewhere where you get that.

That being said, it also helps to learn a little bid about what you want to do.

First, bid/ask is hard to get for forex - it is extremely broker dependant as there is no exchange.

Second. ChangeInpercent - ever heard of that thing called "calculate yourself"? ;)

What you go to is Yahoos "download quotes as csv". It does exactly that - give you a list of quotes as csv file. not more, not less.

There are other services and APIs available. Go and use them if Yahoo does not fullfill your needs with this API you insist on using now.

Answer (score 1):

You might find "inspiration" for your task-at-hand, here: [A C# class for downloading Yahoo!Finance data](http://autospreader.wordpress.com/2011/01/17/a-c-class-for-downloading-yahoofinance-data/)

And, you can find the list of available tags here:[Downloading Yahoo data](http://www.gummy-stuff.org/Yahoo-data.htm)